# How do I make my content appear horizontally?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a Movie website using PHP, HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

I want to display the movies (image, title, some information) horizontally such that there will be 3 movies per row. Currently, the movies are displayed vertically.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$display_content .= '
    <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="d-inline">
            <img src="'.$sub_row["poster_url"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
            <h4>'.$sub_row["title"].'</h4>
            <p>'.$sub_row["description"].'</p>
            <p>'.$sub_row["duration"].'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
```

Comment: There is only 1 div in this code. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I want to display images (together with the title and description, etc) horizontally (3 per row). These content will be fetched from database and display on the website. Currently, I can fetch and display on the website. However, the content are displayed horizontally instead of 3 content per row.

Comment: either use flexboxes or css-grid.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @tacoshy i tried these two methods but it did not work... is PHP possibly causing a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap .flex-row to set a horizontal direction. I hope i got your question right.

```
$display_content .= '
    <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
           <div class="p-2">
            <img src="'.$sub_row["poster_url"].'" class="img-responsive 
             img-thumbnail"/>
           </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <h4>'.$sub_row["title"].'</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <p>'.$sub_row["description"].'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <p>'.$sub_row["duration"].'</p>
        </div>
 
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    ';
```

Comment: i have edited the question for clarity. i have also tried this method that you shared, however it still does not display the movies horizontally. the images are still displayed vertically, only the content is displayed horizontally. however, I want 3 movies per row.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the parent  in your code the following CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 33%;
```

Another thing you can do is use bootstrap classes by wrapping each row with the "row" class and every immediate child of "row" can have the class "col-sm".  Alternatively you can just give each instance of "container mt-5 text-center" an additional class of "col-sm-4".  Since bootstrap's grid system using 12 columns, "col-sm-4" will size the div to take up a third of the parent width.  Check out [Bootstrap's document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) for more information.  Bootstrap also supports flex boxes as well.

Comment: hi, thank you for taking time to answer my question. i have tried the CSS method you have mentioned as well as the Bootstrap Grid System but to no avail.... I have also tried flex boxes but it would not work...